# PHP imap_search function with DigitalOcean droplet not working

Tags: php, outlook, imap, digital-ocean

I am using PHP(php7.2)imap_search function for my Codeigniter application which connects with outlook mail,

In Config file the username and hostname are given,

```
Mailbox_hostname={outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert/authuser=aaaa@bbb.com}
Mailbox_username=aaaa@bbb.com
Mailbox_password=xxxxx
```

The controller code looks like below,

```
$imap_resource = imap_open($mailbox, $username, $password);
$search_sender = 'abc@xyz.com';
$search = 'FROM "' . $search_sender . '" ON "06 April 2022"';
$emails = imap_search($imap_resource, $search);
```

This code is deployed to two servers(Staging and Production) which are hosted in digitalocean droplet.
This works in Staging and $emails returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3652
    [1] => 3659
)
```

but does not work on the production server. It gives an empty response.

Are there any specific mail settings to be checked or configured on the server-side to get this working? Or possibly any firewall causing the issue?

Note:- imap_open works, I am getting the IMAP resource id correctly, but imap_search only fails.

Comment: Your dates are not in the correct format. See the grammar for 'date-text' on page 84 of https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3501#page-84.  It should look like "6-Apr-2022"

Comment: But as I mentioned in the question above, this works well in one of the servers and in my localhost as well. It shows empty responses only in the live server.

Comment: Just because it “works here” doesn’t mean it’s correct.  First: fix your code to be compliant, then see if it works.  You asked what might be wrong, so I told you.

Comment: I will try your solution of date format but are there any such issues with the imap_search function to be checked as well?

Comment: Pretty much exactly what you write is exactly what's sent to the server.

Comment: Changing the date format doesn't work either

Comment: I guess: are you sure there are matching emails?  Have you tried other searches? (eg, just the sender or just the date?, or just ‘all’)?  I don’t think there’s any settings you should be changing, so you’re at troubleshooting and debugging now.